# background on ul to wrap the height of the tallest child?

Tags: html, list, css, drop-down-menu, height

I know there have been a lot of similar questions but none of the solutions worked for me.  the predominant answer was to have `overflow: hidden;` on the `ul` but that's no good for me because the way i have overflow coded is essential for the menu and its transitions.

essentially i have a 2 column drop-down menu.  the left column is the submenu list, the right column is an image.  each main menu item has a different number of submenu items and sometimes even less than the height of the img. i want to fill the background of the `ul class="twinsub"` but i can't get it to pick up same as the height of the tallest list whether that be the image or the submenu list.  i have tried everything i can think of with no success.

here are a couple of images to illustrate what i am trying to do:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

here is the code:

[Updated JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/758qtrxd/8/)

HTML:

```
<section id="menuWrapper">
<nav id="menu" class="cf" role="navigation">
    <!-- Main Nav Start -->
    <ul id="main-nav" class="clearfix">
        <!----------------------------------------- Solutions ------------------>
        <li id="technology" class="parent menu-item"><a href="Solutions.html">Solutions</a>

            <ul class="twinsub">
                <li class="twinmultisub twinleft">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="solutions-turnkey" class="menu-item"><a href="Solutions-turnkey.html">Turnkey Development</a>

                        </li>
                        <li id="solutions-financing" class="menu-item"><a href="Solutions-Financing.html">Financial Modeling</a>

                        </li>
                        <li id="solutions-execution" class="menu-item"><a href="Solutions-Execution.html">World-Class Execution</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="twinmultisub twinimg">
                    <section>
                        <img class="menuimage" src="http://milkytech.com/images/industry.png" />
                    </section>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="technology" class="parent menu-item"><a href="Services.html">Services</a>

            <ul class="twinsub">
                <li class="twinmultisub twinleft">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="services-devlopment" class="menu-item"><a href="Services-Devlopment.html">Development & Financing</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="services-design" class="menu-item"><a href="Services-Design.html">Design & Engineering</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="services-construction" class="menu-item"><a href="Services-Construction.html">Construction & Procurement</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="services-operations" class="menu-item"><a href="Services-operations.html">Operations & Maintenance</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="twinmultisub twinimg">
                    <section>
                        <img class="menuimage" src="http://milkytech.com/images/industry.png" />
                    </section>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
#menu {
    display:inline-block;
    clear:both;
    height:auto;
}
#menu ul {
    margin:0;
}
#menu li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
#menu > ul > li > a {
    display:block;
    line-height: .4em;
}
/* Submenu (second level) */
 #menu li > ul {
    position:absolute;
    top:auto;
    left:0;
    width:180px;
    max-height:0;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index:99999;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#menu ul li:hover ul {
    visibility: visible;
    max-height: 330px;
    width: 204px;
    overflow: visible;
}
#menu ul li > ul:hover {
    overflow:visible;
}
#menu li > ul li {
    height:36px;
    width:100%;
}
#menu li > ul li:last-child {
    height: 35px;
}
#menu li > ul li a {
    padding: 11px 15px;
    height: 35px;
    color: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
ul.twinsub {
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
    width:408px !important;
    border-right: none !important;
    background-color: #5d6f82 !important;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul.twinsub > li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: none !important;
    background: #FFF;
    line-height: 38px;
}
li.twinmultisub {
    display: block;
    width: 50% !important;
}
.menuimage {
    width: 100% !important;
    margin-left: 1px;
    border-right: none;
}
li.twinimg {
    float: left;
    border: none;
}
li.twinleft {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    border-right: none !important;
}
li.twinheader {
    width: 50% !important;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 14px;
    font-size: .9em;
    background-color: #5d6f82 !important;
    color: #FFF;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding a wrapping div around the inner ul, and add a background color to that one.

This example should make a good beginning

```css
.wrapp {
    background: #13385F;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, nav, section, summary {
    display: block;
}
a {
    background: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:active, a:hover {
    outline: 0;
}
nav ul, nav ol {
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
#menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#menuWrapper {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 15px auto 15px;
}
#menu {
    display:inline-block;
    clear:both;
    height:auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 9px 10px -9px rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 9px 10px -9px rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.8);
    box-shadow: 0px 9px 10px -9px rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.8);
}
#menu ul {
    margin:0;
}
#menu li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
#menu > ul > li > a {
    padding:25px 19px 20px;
    border-bottom:3px solid transparent;
    margin-right:0px;
    color:#6D6E70;
    font: 1em'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display:block;
    line-height: .4em;
}
#menu > ul > li:last-child > a {
    font-size: 1em;
}
#menu > ul > li:hover > a {
    color:#5999db;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #5999db;
}
#menu > ul li.selected > a, #menu > ul li.selected:hover > a {
    color:#3F9944;
    border-color:#FFF100;
}
/* Submenu (second level) */
 #menu li > .wrapp > ul {
    position:absolute;
    top:auto;
    left:0;
    width:180px;
    max-height:0;
    /* -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px 2px 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow:         0px 2px 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); */
    visibility: none;
    z-index:99999;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.2s ease, visibility 0s linear 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.2s ease, visibility 0s linear 0.5s;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.2s ease, visibility 0s linear 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: max-height 0.2s ease, visibility 0s linear 0.5s;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease, visibility 0s linear 0.5s;
    background: inherit !important;
}
#menu ul li:hover ul {
    visibility: visible;
    max-height: 330px;
    width: 204px;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    overflow: visible;
    border: 1px solid #EEE;
    border-top: 0;
}
#menu ul li > ul:hover {
    overflow:visible;
}
#menu li > ul li {
    height:36px;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
    padding-top:0;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: #13385F;
    color: #FFF;
    opacity: 1;
}
#menu li > ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom:none;
    height: 35px;
}
#menu li > ul li a {
    background: rgba(19, 57, 95, 0.3);
    padding: 11px 15px;
    height: 35px;
    color: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    font: 10px'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}
#menu li > ul li:hover > a {
    color: #3B3B3B;
    background: #5999db;
}
#menu li > ul li.selected > a, #menu li > ul li.selected:hover > a {
    color: #3B3B3B;
    background: #FFF;
}
ul.twinsub {
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
    width:408px !important;
    border-right: none !important;
    background-color: #5d6f82 !important;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul.twinsub > li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: none !important;
    background: #FFF;
    line-height: 38px;
}
li.twinmultisub {
    display: block;
    width: 50% !important;
}
.menuimage {
    width: 100% !important;
    margin-left: 1px;
    border-right: none;    
    line-height: 0 !important;
    font-size: 0 !important;
}
li.twinimg {
    float: left;
    border: none;
}
li.twinimg section {
    line-height: 0;
}
.borderleft {
    border-left: 1px solid #EEE;
}
li.twinleft {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    border-right: none !important;
}
li.twinheader {
    width: 50% !important;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 14px;
    font-size: .9em;
    background-color: #5d6f82 !important;
    color: #FFF;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<section id="menuWrapper">
    <nav id="menu" class="cf" role="navigation">
        <!-- Main Nav Start -->
        <ul id="main-nav" class="clearfix">
            <!----------------------------------------- Solutions ------------------>
            <li id="technology" class="parent menu-item"><a href="Solutions.html">Solutions</a>
<div class="wrapp">
    <ul class="twinsub">
                    <li class="twinmultisub twinleft">
                
                        <ul>
                            <li id="solutions-turnkey" class="menu-item"><a href="Solutions-turnkey.html">Turnkey Development</a>

                            </li>
                            <li id="solutions-financing" class="menu-item"><a href="Solutions-Financing.html">Financial Modeling</a>

                            </li>
                            <li id="solutions-execution" class="menu-item"><a href="Solutions-Execution.html">World-Class Execution</a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="twinmultisub twinimg">
                        <section>
                            <img class="menuimage" src="http://milkytech.com/images/industry.png" />
                        </section>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="technology" class="parent menu-item"><a href="Services.html">Services</a>
<div class="wrapp">
                <ul class="twinsub">
                    <li class="twinmultisub twinleft">
                        <ul>
                            <li id="services-devlopment" class="menu-item"><a href="Services-Devlopment.html">Development & Financing</a>
                            </li>
                            <li id="services-design" class="menu-item"><a href="Services-Design.html">Design & Engineering</a>
                            </li>
                            <li id="services-construction" class="menu-item"><a href="Services-Construction.html">Construction & Procurement</a>
                            </li>
                            <li id="services-operations" class="menu-item"><a href="Services-operations.html">Operations & Maintenance</a>
                            </li>
                            <li id="services-construction" class="menu-item"><a href="Services-Construction.html">Construction & Procurement</a>
                            </li>
                            <li id="services-operations" class="menu-item"><a href="Services-operations.html">Operations & Maintenance</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="twinmultisub twinimg">
                        <section>
                            <img class="menuimage" src="http://milkytech.com/images/industry.png" />
                        </section>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</section>
```

Just remeber to fix the css on the menu. And the section around the image, and the image itself needs a line-height of 0.

Comment: cool, thank you.  But why does the wrap take the height of its contents but not the ul?

Comment: I just added the wrap and it screws up the whole menu.  what other css did you change?

Comment: It wrapps the whole ul, including the image and the list, whatever is the tallest.

And you have to change the following line:

`/* Submenu (second level) */
 #menu li > .wrapp > ul {`